# Контейнер для коллизий в хеш-таблице

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

В каноничной хеш-таблице в случае возниконовения коллизий элементы с равным хешем помещаются в связный список. Это приводит к тому, что поиск по контейнеру стоит O(n). Почему для контейнера не использовать другую структуру данных? Например, красно-черное дерево. Или другую хеш-таблицу с другим хешем. Поиск и удаление в таком случае удешевляется. Правда, вставка становится заметно дороже. Цена вставки новых элементов перевешивает цену поиска? Есть ли какие-нибудь библиотеки в любом из современных языков, что позволяют выбирать контейнер для коллизий? Например, можно было бы придумать такой случай: сначала я заполняю хеш-таблицу, а после точно знаю, что мне очень сильно понадобится быстрый поиск - так я возьму и преобразую контейнеры в более подходящие. Или я заранее осознаю стоимость вставки, но поиск все равно гораздо важней.

Comment: Для начала, списки для разрешения коллизий — не единственный метод.

Comment: @VladD, не единственный, но есть ли способы менять его? Понятно, что можно свой класс написать, но неужели никто не предоставляет гибкой хеш-таблицы, которую я могу подогнать под свои нужды, осознавая все минусы и плюсы?

Comment: А почему поиск по O(n)? Поиск по хеш-таблице O(1) же.

Comment: @VladD, по самой хеш таблице константа, а по списку с коллизиями - O(n), что в худшем случае большого числа коллизий приводит к поиску O(n) уже по самой таблице. Поэтому _внезапно_ меня осенило, что поиск по коллизиям можно оптимизировать, используя не список. Или использовать список, когда поиск не нужен. Подгонять хеш-таблицу под свои нужды, короче. Не припоминаю, чтобы где-то видел реализации такой таблицы. Неужто никому никогда не нужно было?

Comment: Не-не, _весь_ поиск O(1). При увеличении заполнения таблицы больше, чем load factor, происходит перестройка таблицы, так что асимптотика O(1) сохраняется. Так что при росте размера таблицы к-во bucket'ов время от времени растёт.

Comment: Хороший, интересный вопрос. Если Вам действительно не повезло и все данные попали в малое число "бакетов" (цепочек), то скорее надо подумать над динамической оптимизацией хэш-функции (с последующей реорганизацией таблицы), нежели над деревьями для разрешения коллизий. Вообще, при размышлениях над оптимизацией не надо забывать о памяти, которую будут занимать служебные данные (указатели и т.п.), о размере кэшей и о том, что в современных компах последовательный доступ намного быстрее случайного (даже к данным в кэше). Конечно, я рассуждаю тут не о библиотечных реализациях...

Comment: @avp: Я помню, мы обсуждали как-то вопросы перестройки хеш-таблиц ещё на Хэшкоде. А ещё, методов разрешения коллизий, оказывается, [о-го-го как много](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution).

Comment: При правильно подобранном load factor'е, коллизий немного, и длина списка составляет в среднем пару элементов. При этом линейный поиск будет скорее всего быстрее, чем сложный поиск в дереве (дерево даже для поиска начинает становиться эффективнее при большом количестве элементов, т. к. более сложная логика и нужна не проверка равенства, а сравнение на больше/меньше).

Comment: @VladD, да, я хотел было обсудить (и даже намекнул, говоря о последовательном доступе в своем комменте) -- `The variant called array hash table uses a dynamic array to store all the entries ... This variation makes more efficient use of CPU caching and the translation lookaside buffer (TLB), because slot entries are stored in sequential memory positions` (из Вашей ссылки), но что-то меня отвлекло.

Comment: @VladD, вообще, должен признать, я и половины рассмотренных там методов не знаю. Будем надеяться, ТС увидит Вашу ссылку и изучит весь багаж.

Comment: @avp: Да и я не знаю, думал, что используется лишь связный список и открытая адресация. Но как оказалось...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Поиск будет давать `O(n)` в случае крайне плохого хэша, когда все элементы будут иметь один и тот же хэш. При нормально подобранной хэш-функции получается `O(1)`.

Однако в случае алгоритмов стандарт не написан :), так что да, вполне можно использовать и иные методы разрешения коллизий. Список можно заменять деревом, массивом или даже иной хэш-таблицей с другой хэш-функцией - в конце-концов, идеальное хеширование (см., например, Кормен и др. *Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ*) именно так и поступает.

Вопрос в заложенных в `O()` константах. При небольших размерах цепочек поиск (и особенно вставка, когда она играет роль) в них может проводиться быстрее за счет малой константы, чем в более быстрой, но более сложной структуре.

Более того, тут уже начинают играть свою роль и другие факторы, такие как использование кэша процессора и т.п. не совсем *алгоритмические* мелочи.

Так что для достижения максимального быстродействия, пожалуй, есть только один путь - практически-экспериментальный, и давать он может для каждой связки задача+машина свое решение...

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от решаемой задачи и для каждой задачи можно подобрать соответствующую структуру данных.

Самая быстрая коллекция элементов - это одноранговый массив, скорость доступа к элементу которой не намного больше прямого доступа, следовательно идеальная хеш коллекция для **int** типа - это массив размером **int.Max**.

По моим собственным исследованиям (а я делал с десяток разных вариантов хеш таблиц) наиболее универсальным вариантом является как раз таки "канонический", потому в случае хорошо распределенного хеша предполагает скорость операции ~O(1). Повторюсь, он **наиболее универсальный**.

Конечно в чистом виде доступ O(1) хеш таблицы примерно в 3 раза ниже О(1) массива из-за дополнительных внутренних проверок, но пока системы не имеют бесконечной памяти с мгновенным ее выделением в любом объеме, чтобы можно было создавать массивы максимальных размеров.

С другой стороны если вы имеете жестко ограниченный размер таблицы скажем в 64 элемента, а хеш заполняемых данных в большинстве случаев кратен 64, то обычный вариант даст ~O(n) для любой операции и вся прелесть использования хеш таблиц теряется. В этом случае проще использовать бинарное дерево в чистом виде.